# Using scollector with bosun and not OpenTSDB

Tags: opentsdb, bosun, scollector

I'm trying to run scollector on my windows server and send collected data into bosun server. I'm not running any OpenTSDB server, but I read in scollectors [documentation](https://godoc.org/bosun.org/cmd/scollector) that it can send metadata into OpenTSDB **or** bosun.

> Unlike tcollector, scollector is a single binary where all collectors
>   are compiled into scollector itself. scollector supports external
>   collectors, but your goal should be to use those temporarily until the
>   go version is written or the target system send data directly to
>   **OpenTSDB or Bosun**. scollector has native collectors for Linux, Darwin,
>   and Windows and can pull data from other systems such as AWS, SNMP,
>   and vSphere.

I'm running this in command line:

```
"scollector-windows-amd64.exe" -h external-server-name:8070
```

it gives me:

```
2016/03/08 10:06:46 info: main.go:187: OpenTSDB host: external-server-name:8070
2016/03/08 10:06:47 error: queue.go:87: 404 Not Found
2016/03/08 10:06:47 error: queue.go:93: 404 page not found
2016/03/08 10:06:47 info: queue.go:103: restored 4, sleeping 5s
```

When I'm navigating into external-server-name:8070 I can see bosun dashboard page. How can I tell scollector that it should send data to bosun server and skip sending it to OpenTSDB. Can I specify that `-h` option refers to bosun server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need a backend for bosun. Currently the [config](https://bosun.org/configuration) supports tsdbHost, graphiteHost, or influxHost. When you send data to http://external-server-name:8070/api/put it just forwards it to http://tsdbHost/api/put.

I don't think Graphite support the opentsdb put format, so you probably can't use scollector to send metrics to Graphite. [Influx supports the opentsdb protocol](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/pull/1291#issuecomment-136879203) so you can try pointing scollector at an instance of [tsdbrelay](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/releases) which forwards metrics to the influxdb opentsdb port and sends a copy to bosun for indexing:

```
#Listen on 5252 for metrics, forward to local influxdb on 4242
#and send to local Bosun on 8070 so it can index the tags/metrics
/opt/tsdbrelay/tsdbrelay -b localhost:8070 -t localhost:4242 -l 0.0.0.0:5252
```